# UICollectionViewCell change when selected

Tags: ios, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to animate cell when it did selected, but my code don't animate image hiding.

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
PageCell *selectedCell = [self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

selectedCell.pageImg.hidden = YES;
[selectedCell.pageSnipper startAnimating];

[[PageStore sharedStore] likeAndUpdatePageAtIndex:indexPath.item];

[collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]];

selectedCell.pageImg.hidden = NO;
[selectedCell.pageSnipper stopAnimating];

[self updateLikeCountWithNumberOfLikes:1];
}
```

Comment: What kind of animation are you trying to accomplish ?

Comment: Hide the image `selectedCell.pageImg` while function `[[PageStore sharedStore] likeAndUpdatePageAtIndex:indexPath.item];` is calculated. And show a new image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hidden is unfortunately not an animatable property.

The best way to animate hiding a view is to animate the alpha of the view using something like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
    selectedCell.pageImg.alpha = 0.0f;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [[PageStore sharedStore] likeAndUpdatePageAtIndex:indexPath.item];
    [collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
        selectedCell.pageImg.alpha = 1.0f;
    }];
}];
```

This will make the image invisible, and then visible again after the updates complete.